# Gridview filter resetting on paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I'm binding from my database within my onload method.

As shown:

```
      if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connstring);
           SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Coffees ORDER BY coffeeName ASC", sqlcon);
           SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           adp.Fill(ds);
           GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
           GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

I'm allowing my users to filter the gridview on their search term. The issue I'm following at the moment is that when i change pages, the filter is lost.

I have read I need to rebind the filter eachtime and this is where im getting stuck.

Here is my filter:

```
        private void setGrid(string searchTerm)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string item = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            SqlCommand sqlcmdd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Coffees WHERE " + searchTerm + " = '" + item + "'", sqlcon);
            SqlDataAdapter adpp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmdd);
            DataSet dss = new DataSet();
            adpp.Fill(dss);
            GridView1.DataSource = dss.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

As shown above I have an if statement that handles the Postback. Postback is something I still have to try and get my head around but I believe what this is doing is reloading the grid if its a Postback. I have tried to change this so if it is a Postback it is not affected but this just ignores the filter all together.

Hopefully someone can give me an idea where I'm going wrong. And How I can apply the filter acrodd all of y pages.

Comment: it will obviously be lost as u might be DataBinding the gridview again on paging event.

Comment: @PraveenNambiar I can see this, but what is the correct way to stop it?

Comment: there is no need of that `IsPostBack` on the function `setGrid()`. u might be calling the function setgrid on a button event..right?

Comment: @PraveenNambiar Yes you are correct, I'm calling it on a button click. I have removed the if statement but still the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

I saved the search term as a viewstate variable, then applied in my page index changing method  an if to check if it was null or not. Then I either re-bound the grid on the searchterm, or a standard bind to show all the results.